# Webapp becomes sluggish on Tomcat

Tags: performance, tomcat7

I have a web app (spring/hibernate) running on Tomcat 7.0.23. The symptom
is that after running for few days (4 to 5 days typically) the response
becomes very slow. The page that usually loads in 2 seconds takes anywhere
from 30 to 50 seconds. A restart brings the response back to normal (2
sec). I have taken thread dumps before and after. I see the thread in
question (which is taking longer time to respond) has a lock. Here is the
snippet.

```
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
    at
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    at
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
    - locked <0x0000000799446298> (a
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
    at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Upon looking into the code, there is a synchronized method and that
explains the lock. But, I am wondering if the locking is slowing the things
down  then why didn't it manifest from the fresh start and why only after
running for few days. Wondering where to look. Any clues? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you run a basic test using something like jmeter or soapui.

Increase the load slowly and see what happens: is the avg time getting through the roof or is it just getting a bit slower ? Are you getting errors or is it still up and running ?

Meanwhile, open visualvm and have a look at your VM. You may bump into a memory pbs, GC busy trying to free unused instances or maybe locks ? use the thread dump and heap dump features to get a bit further.

I performed such a test on a very old app and discovered that log4j 1.x had big problems with multi-threading: upgraded to log4j 2 -> problem solved!

Hope this helps.